# List migration from root site to subsite with in the same site collection through Share Gate Migration Tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-migration

we require a large List more than 15000 items in it to migrate from root site to one of the subsite..

the list has couple of lookup columns..

Is it possible to migrate List/library in the root site to the subsite in the

> ShareGate Migration Tool

it would be helpful if any of you can share some usefull links

Answer (score 0):

You could save the list as template. Then download the template file from root site and upload it to the subsite. Then use this template to create a list.

You also could achieve this using Share Gate.

More information is here:

https://sharegate.com/blog/copy-list-in-sharepoint-to-office365-tool

Comment: Save list as template does not work as it has more than 5000 items..